# getting a list of updated values of rows of jsp in servlet after checking checkbox

Tags: jsp, servlets

when i try to get value after update the two or more row columns and try to get in servlet ,i m getting only one value in servlet and i have to send two or more row or we can say a updated list of project to another servlet what i m trying to do i have write her plz help me out i m new at servlet and jsp

```
     <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import="com.nousinfo.tutorial.employee.service.model.bo.EmployeeProjectBO"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
    <%@page import="com.nousinfo.tutorial.employee.service.model.bo.EmployeeBO"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Update Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"></link>

</head>

    <body >

        <form action="ProjectUpdateServlet">
        <table border="1" width="500" id="tbl">
                <tr>
                    <td width="234"><b>click</b></td>   
                    <td width="119"><b>Employee Number</b></td>
                    <td width="234"><b>Project Code</b></td>
                    <td width="234"><b>Start Date</b></td>
                    <td width="234"><b>End Date</b></td>
                    <td width="234"><b>Role</b></td>

                </tr>

            <c:forEach var="employeeProjectBO" items="${sessionScope.projectList}">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox"  value='${employeeProjectBO.projectCode}' name="projectCode"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value='${employeeProjectBO.employeeNumber}' name="employeeNumber" readonly="readonly"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value='${employeeProjectBO.projectCode}' name="projectCode" readonly="readonly"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value='${employeeProjectBO.startDate}'name="startDate"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value='${employeeProjectBO.endDate}' name="endDate"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value='${employeeProjectBO.role}' name="role"/></td>
                        <td><input type="hidden" name="updateStatusProject" value="M" /></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>




                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <br />
                <table width="200" border="0" align="center">
                    <tr>

                        <td><center>
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="update" onclick="self.close()">
                            </center></td>

                        <td><center>
                                <input type="button" name="cancle" value="cancle"
                                    onclick="self.close()"/>
                            </center></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <hr size="1" width="786">
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

and this is my servlet

```
  package com.nousinfo.tutorial;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.nousinfo.tutorial.employee.service.model.bo.EmployeeProjectBO;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ProjectUpdateServlet
 */
public class ProjectUpdateServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ProjectUpdateServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            String[] projectCode=   request.getParameterValues("checkedProject");
             for(int i=0; i<projectCode.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(projectCode[i]);}
        System.out.println(request.getSession().getAttribute("projectList"));
        if (request.getParameter("submit") != null) {
            request.getSession().setAttribute("employeeProjectBO",
                    setEmployeeProject(request));
        }

    }

    public EmployeeProjectBO setEmployeeProject(HttpServletRequest request) {
        EmployeeProjectBO employeeProjectBO = new EmployeeProjectBO();
        String[] projectCode=   request.getParameterValues("checkedProject");

         for(int i=0; i<projectCode.length; i++) {

        employeeProjectBO.setUpdateStatus(request.getParameter("updateStatusProject").charAt(0));

        employeeProjectBO.setEmployeeNumber(Long.parseLong(request
                .getParameter("employeeNumber")));
        employeeProjectBO.setProjectCode(request.getParameter("projectCode"));
        employeeProjectBO.setStartDate(new java.sql.Date(getDate(
                request.getParameter("startDate")).getTime()));
        employeeProjectBO.setEndDate(new java.sql.Date(getDate(
                request.getParameter("endDate")).getTime()));
        employeeProjectBO.setRole(request.getParameter("role"));
        System.out.println(request.getParameter("role"));}
        return employeeProjectBO;
    }

    private static Date getDate(String source) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        try {
            return format.parse(source);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new Date();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You also seem new at English and punctuation. Please find someone who could rewrite your question, because I can't understand it. And add a bit more context to it: what are you trying to do?

Comment: @JBNizet actually after changing the value of more than one column in more than one row ,when i checked my rows , i m not able to get those multiple updated value in  my servlet except of one top row .So how to get these list of updated value in my servlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) 
You should create different names to checkboxes
name="projectCode" add for example employeeProjectBO.projectCode to this input name

2) in servlet

```
for(int i=0; i<projectCode.length; i++) {
request.getParameterValues("checkedProject"+projectCode.getProjectCode);
…
}
```